# Fourier analysis of time series

Tags: fft, dft

I need to do Fourier analysis of time series in Java or C#. How to start doing Fourier analysis of time series? 
Is there any algorithm? How many types of Fourier analysis I can use?

Comment: There has to be a lot about this topic on the internet. You should clearly google this before posting such a broad question.

Comment: "How to start ...?" Install a library of appropriate routines and start writing code to use it, or write your own routines if you're sufficiently mathematically minded and want the experience. "Is there any algorithm?" Yes, of course. Thousands of them, likely... "How many types ..." All of them, but it's probably better to pick the ones that best help you provide the specific type(s) of analysis you need.

Answer (score 1):

There are already so many programs and routines available for this task, I am surprised that you would have to write another. Do you just need to perform a DFT on some data, or do you actually have to write a completely new program? The type of program you need also depends on several factors. For example, are the inputs real or complex? Do you want a 1-D transform? 2-D transform? etc.

Examples of existing programs that come to mind quickly are FFTW, KISSFFT, FFmpeg, Accelerate framework (for a Mac), and GFFT (on sourceforge). KISSFFT may be the easiest one to translate to Java and C#, if that is what you are planning.

Alternately, you may want to check out the source codes posted on the FFTPACK site, or find a copy of "Numerical Recipes." They may not offer the most up-to-date algorithms, but they get the job done.